# "Song"/Theme played in Hobbit: Battle of Five Armies

Tags: soundtrack, the-hobbit, the-battle-of-the-five-armies

What is that theme/song called that Bombur "plays" when sounding the horn of Erebor and/or the humans play in honor of Thorin (after it "all over")?

Comment: I'm looking for the same track. It's not in the special edition score. It is the horn tribute to thorin from the people of lake town in the city of dale after the fighting is done. Are they planing on releasing an extended edition score? Have we missed it somehow in the score which has been released?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the [Sons Of Durin](https://youtu.be/gleorTAQ3AM?t=2m6s).

In The Hobbit: The Battle of the Five Armies Bombur sounds the horn that signals of [Thorin and the company of dwarves joining the fight](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N7W7ZhTsxeI). You can find all OST on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_of_The_Hobbit_film_series#Track_listing_3).